# When i try to update textfield by entering some text after i clicked done button from keyboard the new edited text will be erased

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

the data fetch from api overrides the new edited text while entering done button from keyboard.

```
TextFormField(
controller: profileController.updateBusinessphoneController..text='${profileController.profileData[index].phoneNumber}',
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 border: OutlineInputBorder(),
 labelText: 'Business Phone',
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                    initialValue: '${profileController.profileData[index].phoneNumber}',
                    controller: profileController.updateBusinessphoneController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Business Phone',
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                initialValue: profileController.businessphoneNumber.value,
                onFieldSubmitted: (newValue){
                  profileController.businessphoneNumber.value=newValue;

                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Business Phone',
                ),
               
              ),
```